# Treating typescript enum as class with list of its instances

Tags: typescript

I've often used such construction in Java:

```
public enum MyMartDiscountCard {
    //List of enum instances
    Progressive(3, 10, 0.01),
    FixedPercent(5, 5, 0);

    //Just like normal class with fields and methods
    private int initial;
    private int max;
    private int ratio;
    public MyMartDiscountCard(int initial, int max, float ratio){...}
    public calculateDiscount(float totalSpent){ 
        return Math.max(initial + totalSpent*ratio, max);
    }
}
```

Now I'm learning Typescript and want to use similar constructions in it.

As I know TS specification does't allow it. But are there any good workaround patterns to declare methods and properties and bind them to enum instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am extrapolating from your question, so this may not be the right answer for you; but I don't see why you need an `enum` here. You have the concept of a discount card, with specializations.

Rather than writing an enum and then having code throughout your program switching and iff-ing off of the type of card, use polymorphism so your whole program only needs to know that there is such as thing as a discount card and doesn't need to know the type at all.

```
class DiscountCard {
    constructor(private initial: number, private max: number, private ratio: number){

    }

    public calculateDiscount(totalSpent: number) { 
        return Math.max(this.initial + totalSpent * this.ratio, this.max);
    }
}

class ProgressiveDiscountCard extends DiscountCard {
    constructor() {
        super(3, 10, 0.01);
    }
}

class FixedPercentDiscountCard extends DiscountCard {
    constructor() {
        super(5, 5, 0);
    }
}

class DoubleFixedDiscountCard extends DiscountCard {
    constructor() {
        super(5, 5, 0);
    }

    public calculateDiscount(totalSpent: number){
        var normalPoints = super.calculateDiscount(totalSpent);

        return normalPoints * 2; 
    }
}
```

Consumers of `DiscountCard` don't need to know which card they use as you put any variations on logic inside of the specializations. The `DoubleFixedDiscountCard` could actually just set up the super class with doubled values, but I wanted to show an example where you override the behaviour in the sub class.

Comment: Yes i think it is good idea. I was too fixed on having everything in one place, like enums do. Anyway i can just put all this derived classes into enum just for structure.